# When do we use strong /biː/ instead of weak /bi/ in english?

Tags: phonology

I am wondering in which context people stress the *be* in English grammar.
Both Wiktionary and Wordrefence have a weak and a strong form in their dictionary : 
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/be#English
and https://www.wordreference.com/enfr/be

I know that for example, the word *has* is used in strong form only when used negatively.

- /aɪ həv si:n hə/
- /aɪ hævnt si:n he/

But for the word *be*, I see no example where we could use it negatively.
If someone could help

Comment: I think this may be better migrated to the English Language & Usage Stack Exchange. But anyway: in the Wiktionary link you post, it doesn't seem to give any weak form, just a UK and US form.

I don't think there is a predictable context for a weak form of 'be'. That is, it would sound really weird to use the 'strong form' of 'have' in a form like *she wouldn't have gone*. I don't think there is a parallel context where a 'weak form' of 'be' is necessary. Having said that, of course there will be common phrases or informal situations where the vowel may be significantly phonetically reduced.

Comment: Might the English Language Learners Stack Exchange be appropriate too?

Comment: Yes, good point!